# How to set NSTextField top-left origin?

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoa, nstextfield

[image]Swift 4.1, Xcode 9.3, cocoa App

How to set NSTextField top left origin so it will always show up as top left regardless of how people zoom in the view?

```
    @IBOutlet weak var inputFromTextField: NSTextField!
    @IBAction func buttonMain(_ sender: NSButton) {
    let labelMain = NSTextField(frame: CGRect(x: Int(view.frame.origin.x) + 10, y: Int(view.frame.origin.y), width: 100, height: 100))
    labelMain.textColor = NSColor.white
    labelMain.drawsBackground = true
    labelMain.backgroundColor = NSColor.orange
    self.view.addSubview(labelMain)
}
```

This show up as left-bottom instead of left-top.
Most of the answer show up is for iOS not cocoa app.

Comment: can you add the UI which type of OP you expect

Comment: okay, I updated the whole thing.

Comment: can you add the OP User interface which type you need

Comment: I'm not sure. Can you show me an example? And what does OP stand for? I'm trying to programmatically set up the label position to top left, so I can't do it with adding constrains. It's like using constrains top left, but with code only.

Comment: you mentioned label but you tried with NSTextField. if u show the ui, its easy to understand

Comment: in cocoa app, I believe both textField and label are NSTextField.

Comment: Do you want to add constraints in code or don't you want to use constraints at all?

Comment: I want to use constraints in code, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add constraints. Programmatically, there are three methods:

- create constraint objects (the hard way)
- use the visual format language (much easier, compatible with all versions)
- use guides (even easier, introduced in macOS 10.11)

I'd give examples, but Apple already has a concise description of all three, with examples, in the [Programmatically Creating Constraints](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/ProgrammaticallyCreatingConstraints.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH16-SW1) section of Auto Layout Guide.